# How to filter result with two tags parameters in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQl query;

```
SELECT prod.* FROM bb_admin.bb_directory_products as prod 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_map_product_category as mapcat ON prod.product_id = mapcat.product_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_categories_products as cat ON mapcat.category_id = cat.category_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_map_product_tag as maptag ON prod.product_id = maptag.product_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_tags as tag ON maptag.tag_id = tag.tag_id 
WHERE (prod.status='1' OR prod.status='3' OR prod.status='5') 
AND prod.is_catalogue='1' AND cat.slug = 'barongs-suits' 
AND tag.title IN ('gray','classic') 
GROUP BY prod.product_id
```

What I want is to display products with tags 'gray' and 'classic'.

I tried `AND tag.title = 'gray' AND tag.title = 'classic'` but its not working well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT prod.* 
FROM bb_admin.bb_directory_products as prod 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_map_product_category as mapcat ON prod.product_id = mapcat.product_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_categories_products as cat ON mapcat.category_id = cat.category_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_map_product_tag as maptag ON prod.product_id = maptag.product_id 
LEFT JOIN bb_admin.bb_tags as tag ON maptag.tag_id = tag.tag_id 
WHERE (prod.status='1' OR prod.status='3' OR prod.status='5') 
AND prod.is_catalogue='1' AND cat.slug = 'barongs-suits' 
AND tag.title IN ('gray','classic') 
GROUP BY prod.product_id
HAVING count(distinct tag.title) = 2
```

Add a `having` clause that makes sure a `product_id` has **both** tags.